# My regular expression isn't capturing the groups correctly

Tags: php, regex

I have a string at some point in my code like this:

```
href="http://mywebsite.com/site/link.php?M=191123&N=34&FL=H&L=7"
```

What I need to grab is everything after `/site/`, so I'm using the following code to attempt this:

```
preg_match("/site\/(.*?)(?:\"|')/i", $href, $pmatch);
$params = json_encode($pmatch);
```

But when I echo `$params`, I get the value of `[]`, so it hasn't matched any groups where it should have?

**EDIT**

The thing is, I use this code in a separate php file:

```
$href = 'href="http://mysite/em/site/link.php?M=191123&N=34&FL=H&L=7"';
preg_match("/site\/([^\"']*)/i", $href, $matches);
$params = $matches[1];

echo $params;
```

AND IT WORKS FINE??

Comment: What's wrong with just doing a zero or more match?  

\/site\/(.*)

Comment: You have `$href="http://mywebsite.com/site/link.php?M=191123&N=34&FL=H&L=7";` or `$href=' some text href=http://mywebsite.com/site/link.php?M=191123&N=34&FL=H&L=7"';`?

Comment: Neither. What my script is doing is going through all links and replacing values in them. So in each iteration, the string is `href="somelink"`

Comment: Show a reproducible example. e.g. define `$href` statically.

Comment: `$href = 'href="http://mysite/em/site/link.php?M=191123&N=34&FL=H&L=7"';`

Comment: 1) use DOMDocument to extract links from your html document. 2) use `parse_url` and `explode` to get the filename.

Comment: It won't even match the expression `/site/`. What the hell??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture everything up to a quote (I assume the the href= and the quotes are part of the text you want to search) then just use this:

```
/site\/([^\"']*)/i
```

By the way your regex works on [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/swyvGD/1) so maybe something else is wrong?

Are you *sure* the last quote is part of the string you want to search? Just change it to this and see if it works:

```
/site\/(.*)/i
```

Actually that shouldn't matter since the previous regex doesn't test for the last quote.

One of your givens is incorrect. Try printing the value of $href just before making the call.

Comment: That's what's confusing me, it works on there, but not in my php. Maybe it's something to do with the string I'm searching. But that's the string I get when I echo it...